# Unable to create dynamic connection in dbcontext in entity framework DB first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just want to pass a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` into my dbcontext base() but the code is not working.

```
public MirrorBranchesEntities(string db)
        : base(ConnectToSqlServer(db))
    {
    }

    public static string ConnectToSqlServer(string catalog)
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = "(local)";
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = catalog;
        sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;             
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "sa";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "Qwer0987";

        var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl";

        return sqlBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

In other words I want to turn this

```
"name=" + connectionStringName + "connectionString=metadata=res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=" + db + ";user id=sa;password=Qwer0987;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot; providerName=System.Data.EntityClient"
```

to sql connection string builder to put in my dbcontext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are returning

```
return sqlBuilder.ToString();
```

May be

```
return entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()
```

And replace

```
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient";
```

by

```
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexcei. Sorry for the late answer approval. Got knocked-out. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302786%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Your code should return:

entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString();

Comment: I am getting this exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Comment: what are you using database? Is you sure that prodiver name is correct?

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165158/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install