# Exception with Entity Framework in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am facing an exception while running the below code,

```
// Create a connection object for entity connection.
EntityConnection con = new EntityConnection(connString);
```

The exception message is

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

and the inner exception is

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

in `System.Data.Entity` dll.

The above mentioned issue occurs only when run the project on .NET 4.0 and all other framework projects are executing fine with provided connection.

Could anyone please let me know, why exception while working with Entity Framework in 4.0 .NET framework?

Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: Install Asp.net MVC3 and check your connectionstring properly.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165158/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install

Comment: @AbhayDixit - I am using windows forms applications

Comment: @Amal - to which database server are you trying to connect? MSSQL? Which version?

Comment: Can you show the connectionstring?

Comment: @PeterBons - `<connectionStrings><add name="NorthwindGridEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=D:\ImportantSampels\NorthwindGrid.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>`

Comment: the above connection string works fine with above 4.0 frameworks

Comment: Any update on this?